# ASP.NET core authorize role with AD group from appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

It seems like it should be really easy, as on my controller this works:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "domain\\ad_group")]
public class MyController : Controller
```

However I would like to specify the "domain\ad_group" from appsettings, rather than hard-coded.
I realize the 'proper' solution is to use eg. the EF roles/policies etc, however this is a very tiny application so I'm looking for something a bit more lightweight.

Can I get the AD group from appsettings in a simple way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the attribute: 
`[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicyName")]`

In the `ConfigureServices` method perform the following 2 steps:

1. Read the required role (AD Group) from the appsettings.json file.

2. Add that role to this policy using the RequireRole method.

Code for Step 1:

```
Configuration.GetSection("NameOfSectionInAppSettings").Bind(ObjectTheSectionIsMappedTo);
```

Code for Step 2:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{ options.AddPolicy("MyPolicyName", policy => policy.RequireRole(ObjectTheSectionIsMappedTo.AdGroupProperty)); });
```

This works for one of the tiny applications I developed :)

Comment: Great I didn't realise the RequireRole method can take an AD group name - good find..